# Undefined self module method called in method_added

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am trying to implement a hooker for class methods, something like `before_action` and `after_action`. The problem is if I define a method inside module, with `define_method` or normally with `def do_before; puts 'do_before called'; end` inside `method_added` gets undefined. So how can I call a `module method` inside `method_added`?

```
module Hooker

  [:before, :after].each do |element|
    define_method("#{element}_action") do |name|
      puts "#{element}_action called with parameter #{name}"
    end
    define_method("do_#{element}") do
      puts "do_#{element} called"
    end
  end
  def method_added(name)
    return if @filtering # Don't add to original_ methods
    @filtering = true

    alias_method :"original_#{name}", name
    define_method name do |*args|
      do_before # undefined method `do_before' for #<Bar:0x007ff2f183c318>
      self.send("original_#{name}", *args)
      do_after # undefined method `do_after' for #<Bar:0x007ff2f183c318>
    end

    @filtering = false
  end
end

class Bar
  extend Hooker

  before_action 'foo2'
  after_action 'bar2'

  def my_func
    puts 'MyFunc called'
  end
end

Bar.new.my_func
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you're using
 - `extend`

> adds the specified module's methods and constants to the target's
>   metaclass

but you also need - `include`

> it mixes in the specified module's methods as instance methods in the
>   target class

```
# some code goes here

class Bar
  extend Hooker
  include Hooker

  before_action 'foo2'
  after_action 'bar2'

  def my_func
    puts 'MyFunc called'
  end
end

Bar.new.my_func
=> before_action called with parameter foo2
=> after_action called with parameter bar2
=> do_before called
=> MyFunc called
=> do_after called
```

Much more clearly is to separate this to different modules.

Comment: Works perfect, but is there any way/trick to not have to do the 2 steps in the class? Maybe using self.extended or inherited?

Comment: Not sure, but take a look on [Module#prepend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend), One big advantage of this is being able to override methods in a safer way, rather than using alias or tricks like alias_method_chain. happy coding!

Comment: Not firing ... Tried with this `def self.extended(base); base.send :include, self; end` but still not working.

Comment: on the `Hooker` module `extended` not firing?

Comment: Prepend is not firing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution, whereby you don't need to explicitly call both `extend` and `include` in the class:

```
module Hooker
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    [:before, :after].each do |element|
      define_method("#{element}_action") do |name|
        puts "#{element}_action called with parameter #{name}"
      end
      define_method("do_#{element}") do
        puts "do_#{element} called"
      end
    end
  end

  def method_added(name)
    return if @filtering # Don't add to original_ methods
    @filtering = true

    alias_method :"original_#{name}", name
    define_method name do |*args|
      do_before
      self.send("original_#{name}", *args)
      do_after
    end

    @filtering = false
  end
end

class Bar
  include Hooker

  before_action 'foo2'
  after_action 'bar2'

  def my_func
    puts 'MyFunc called'
  end
end

Bar.new.my_func
```

The trick here is that the `Hooker` module is now `extend`ing *though* the `include`.

Comment: Hi, works great as I wanted. I already accepted the other answer, usually if other answer is more reliable is ok to change the acceptance? EDIT: is not working.

Comment: Yes, it's considered fine to [change, or even un-accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93969/369864) the accepted answer. You should choose whichever answer *you found most helpful*. (Or none, if no answer was sufficiently helpful!) I'm not sure why it's not working, however; possibly there's a time limit or something. (I'd be interested to know if you figure it out!)